# Is log(n^2)'s asymptotic order larger than or equals to log(5n)

Tags: algorithm

To compare the asymptotic order of the two functions, I calculated the limit of first function over second function, when n goes to infinity.

The answer was 2 (I had to use l'hopital's rule), which means that for really high values of n, log(n^2) is larger than log(5n)

My question is: is it **incorrect** to say that log(n^2) is asymptotically larger than log(5n)?

My friend told me that when the limit of first function over the second function is a constant, that means that their asymptotic order is equal. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Question better suited at [MathSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This would probably be more on-topic at [Mathematics.SE].

Comment: This question belongs to Computer Science. So probably it should be best suited at CS.SE http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `log (5n) = log 5 + log n`, and `log (n^2) = 2 log n`, so `log(n^2)` is larger than `log 5n`. In addition, we can say that `log(n^2)` is *asymptotically larger* than log 5n. One definition of [Asymptotic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptotic.html) is as follows.

> The term asymptotic means approaching a value or curve arbitrarily
>   closely (i.e., as **some sort of limit** is taken). A line or curve A that
>   is asymptotic to given curve C is called the asymptote of C.

Depending on the context we may ignore constant factors, and write they are in the same order. We may express this by existing notations such as `O`, Θ and Ω. According to the widely accepted definition from the algorithmic standpoint, these two particular functions are asymptotically equivalent:

We say **A(n)** is asymptotically larger than **B(n)** if

> lim <sub>n→∞</sub>A(n)/B(n) = ∞

In this case, the above limit converges to 2 (or reverse version 1/2) so they are asymptotically equal.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that definition of "asymptotically larger"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I don't have my BS textbooks right now :) but I'll find reference for you (It was one of an algorithm books like CLRS or art of computer programmind or ... I can't remember which one, but if you don't trust me I'll show you reference). But now really I don't have anything in hand, you can downvote me till I comment you for reference.

Comment: It's not that I don't trust you, it's just that it's not an intuitive definition (at least IMO).  I would have expected something more like `lim A(n)/B(n) > 1`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, no it's not what you think, for now you can take a look at [small-o definition in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) (it's limit like this in reverse). As I said, when I have an access to my old books, I'll find it (or may be I search around web).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I was about to respond saying "but the OP hasn't mentioned Landau notation", but then I noticed that he/she talks about "order" in the question title.  So given that we're talking about orders, I agree with you!  (So +1).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, As you see in [Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), It uses sentences like: f dominates g asymptotically,... for small omega and small-o, (as you said it's not very clear what was in OPs mind, Also I don't believe wiki can be a good mathematical/algorithmic reference).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: I think you got me confused. My question is that are they asymptotically equal or is log(n^2) asymptotically larger. Are you saying that we can say either?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro, Its depend to context you work on it, In algorithms they are equal. I wrote this in my last part to prevent from confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`log(n^2) = 2 * log(n)` and `log(5n) = log(5) + log(n)`. So both are asymptotically equal when speaking about algorithms.

Comment: Indeed.  But that doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Big-O is just a classification system.  Just because two functions belong to the same Big-O, it doesn't mean it's wrong to say that one is asymptotically larger than the other.

Answer (score 0):

log(n^2)=2*log(n)

Assuming log base 2

Comment: That holds for arbitrary bases, by the way.

Comment: I don't think you have to assume anything about the base of the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit was 2, then it means that log(5n) belongs to O(log(n^2)), doesn't it...